# Phonegap / Cordova InAppBrowser handles content different then Safari/Chrome Mobile

Tags: cordova, viewport, inappbrowser

I open an external page in my Phonegap application with

```
 window.open("https://external.com/external", "_blank", 'location=yes,EnableViewPortScale=yes');
```

Unfortunately the ViewPort is not the same as in the mobile-phones native browser. So if I open the same page in Chrome on my Nexus 4 I see the complete page (correct scaled). If I open the page through the InAppBrowser of Phonegap I see only half of the page and have to scale it  to see the entire page.

The view-port meta tag is the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,user-scalable=no">
```

I also tried to set it to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
```

But then the page has to be scaled in the native Browser and displays correctly in the InAppBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

The above code will open it with correct scaling in phone gap app as it is opening in the Web Browser

Comment: Explaining your code in a bit more detail might be helpful.

Comment: @CharlieFish The above code will open it with correct scaling in phone gap app as it is opening in the Web Browser

Comment: I would suggest editing your answer to include that. The more details you can provide in your answers on Stack Overflow the better.

Comment: @CharlieFish Done :)